# Class object cannot create a magical square due to an indexing problem

Tags: python, class, object, indexing

Attempting to create a magical square (where all the rows, columns and diagonals share the same sum) When testing for n in[1,3,5,7,9,13] the program breaks at value 3 and says IndexError: list index out of range. I've tried running the logic magic square logic by itself in a function instead of method and it returns fine I cannot spot the index problem within the class logic(Also im pretty bad at classes).

```
class MagicSquares():
    def __init__(self,side):
        import copy
        self.side = side
        grid = copy.deepcopy([[0]*int(side)]*int(side))

        x = side / 2
        y = side - 1
        num = 1

        while num <= (side * side):
            if x == -1 and y == side:
                y = side-2
                x = 0

            else:
                if y == side:
                    y = 0
                if x < 0:
                    x = side - 1
            if grid[int(x)][int(y)]:
                y -= 2
                x += 1
                continue
            else:
                grid[int(x)][int(y)] = num
                num += 1
            y += 1
            x -= 1 


    def display(self,side):
        for row in range(side):
            for col in range(side):
                print([row][col])

def main():
    for n in [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]:
        print("Magic Square of size",)
        magic = MagicSquares(n)
        magic.display(n)



main()
```

Comment: Your line `y -= 2` is being executed when `y` is zero. Perhaps there should be some logic to prevent that.

Comment: That `import copy` should be at the top of your module, not in the middle of a class. I would also recommend using `numpy` for some of this, if only just to create the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple indexing error points in your code, I've fixed them up, here's a list of changes

```
grid = copy.deepcopy([[0]*int(side)]*int(side))
```

Changed to

```
self.grid = [[0 for i in range(side)] for i in range(side)]
```

If you want to initialize a nested list with a certain value, don't use multipy. Just use a for loop or comprehension like this. Also put the `grid` variable as a attribute of `self` so that it can be accessed again in the `display` method

Replace references to `grid` with `self.grid` inside the while loop.

I fixed this first, and it stopped the initial `IndexError`, but a second one persisted

```
    def display(self,side):
        for row in range(side):
            for col in range(side):
                print([row][col])
```

Changed to

```
    def display(self):
        for row in range(self.side):
            for col in range(self.side):
                print(self.grid[row][col])
```

Removed the `side` parameter, it is not needed since you have already stored the value of `side` in the object in `__init__` (`self.side = side`).

Finally, that print call you had, `print([row][col])`, is technically a valid expression, just its not doing anything useful and also throws a `IndexError`.  You have created a new list, with 1 element `row`, then indexed that list by a variable `col`.  Whereas what you most likely wanted to do was to get the grid, first index it by the row number, then index it by the col number. that is what I've shown here